# pgrep in my shell script: not counting the script itself?

Tags: grep

This is the behavior of `pgrep` on my **FreeBSD** script:

```
luis@Balanceador:~/Temporal$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pgrep -fl "test.sh"

luis@Balanceador:~/Temporal$ ./test.sh
luis@Balanceador:~/Temporal$
```

No output. This is: the script itself is **not detected** as running. Just like the command-line behavior of `pgrep`. This is fine for me.

And this is the **Linux** (Ubuntu) case:

```
luis@Terminus:~/Temporal$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pgrep -fl "test.sh"

luis@Terminus:~/Temporal$ ./test.sh
4514 bash
luis@Terminus:~/Temporal$
```

As can be seen, the `test.sh` script itself seems to be **detected** as a running process.

I am developing a shell (Bash) **script** that must be able to **stop** and wait if **another instance** of it (same name) is detected, and must work on both Linux and FreeBSD, so I would like to homogeneize the pgrep command for this.

Is there any way to make both of them behave **the same**?

Answers for any derivative like `grep` or `ps` accepted.

**Tested**:

The `-x` (exact) switch from the [Man Page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&sektion=1), but does not work with **parameters** on the scripts (or I don't understand how to make it work). Parameters are not important to detect (they could be whatever) in this case; I just need to detect the main '.sh'  script.

**Further Notes**:

- Please, don't answer like "Use file locking". I actually want to know about the `pgrep` tool.

Comment: What do you want to happen in case multiple instances of the script are running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FreeBSD's `pgrep` excludes ancestors of the `pgrep` process, including the script instance that ran it. Linux's `pgrep` doesn't have a corresponding feature.

You can exclude the script instance manually. The process id to exclude is in `$$`. You do need to be a bit careful to also avoid any subshell: the most straightforward method `pgrep … | grep -v "^$$ "` might list the right-hand side of the pipe if `pgrep` happens to reach it in the process list before `grep` is invoked.

```
instances=$(pgrep -fl "test.sh")
if [[ "$instances" =~ (.*)$'\n'"$$ "[^$'\n']*$'\n'(.*) ]]; then
  instances=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$'\n'${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
elif [[ "$instances" =~ (^|.*$'\n')"$$ "[^$'\n']*($|$'\n'.*) ]]; then
  instances=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

Comment: Your trick of excluding process id with `$$` worked like a charm.

Comment: Or get the pgrep output _before_ starting grep with `printf "%s\n" "$(pgrep -fl test.sh)" | grep -v "^$$ "` or `grep -v "^$$ " <<<"$(pgrep -fl test.sh)"`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `x` to the flags:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
pgrep -flx "pgrep.sh"
```

Tested in Ubuntu and it doesn't print anything to the output (if this is what you want!).

Comment: But according to the man page, that forces parameters concidence, and I don't want that.

Comment: Which way do you want? FreeBSD be like Ubuntu or the other way?

Comment: Well, both methods are accepted. I would personally prefer the FreeBSD way (more logical), but the real disturbance in a program are the differences (you know: code must have too much `if...then` sentences).

Comment: Use a combination of ps and grep. `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -v pgrep.sh`